# Why should I change the subject in this situation? (V的V, V的V sentence structure)

Tags: word-choice

My teacher has recently asked the class to make a sentence with the V的V, V的V sentence structure. I have submitted the following sentence:

> 我的爸爸做事的做事，打字的打字，打电话的打电话，真的很忙。

But my teacher said that the sentence would be better if I changed "我的爸爸" to "公司的人". I don't really understand why such a change improves my sentence, if it actually does. The only difference I can see is that "我的爸爸" is singular, while "公司的人" is plural.

Answer (score 2):

> The only difference I can see is that "我的爸爸" is singular, while "公司的人" is plural.

That is the reason.

[V 的 V] = [the one who v, does v] e.g. "敵兵逃的逃，降的降" = "the enemy soldiers who run, do run; the enemy soldiers who surrender, do surrender". Which means 'some soldiers run, some soldiers surrender'.

打字的打字，打电话的打电话 = the ones who type are typing; the ones who make phone calls are making phone calls = 'some people are typing, some people are making phone calls'

- [the enemy soldiers who run] is the subject; The second [run] is the verb
- [打电话的(人)] is the subject; the second [打电话] is the verb

The reason for the second '打字' in '打字的打字' is '打字的' is a noun that means 'the one who type'. It doesn't mean he is currently typing until you add the verb '打字' after the noun.

Please see this similar question [Grammar: verb + 的 + verb](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/31828/grammar-verb-%e7%9a%84-verb)